# ffplay does not play hls continuously and it stop after a few first segments

Tags: ffmpeg, hls, ffplay

I am using the following command to read a RTSP stream from an IP camera and record it as HLS:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://<user>:<password>@<ip>:<port> -c:v copy -c:a copy -hls_segment_type mpegts -segment_list_type m3u8 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_wrap 5 -hls_time 5 -hls_flags split_by_time -segment_time_delta 1.00 -start_number 1 -segment_list live -reset_timestamps 1 -movflags faststart  live.m3u8`

Everything goes well. However, while I am using ffplay as `ffplay -i live.m3u8`, it only plays a few first segments. Even VLC does play a few first segments too! What am I missing? shall I change my ffmpeg command or what?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You've mixed options from the segment muxer alongside the hls muxer. Use only one, preferably [hls](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2).

Comment: I just simplified the command as follows. BUT no changes and the problem is still there :(

```ffmpeg -i rtsp://<user>:<password>@<ip>:<port> -c:v copy -c:a copy -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_list_size 5 -hls_wrap 5 -hls_time 5 -start_number 1 -reset_timestamps 1 live.m3u8```